# ImageView not center aligning

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically center align ImageView in RelativeLayout but unable to do so. It seems a simple thing but I'm unable to sort out the problem. Here is the xml I defined.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:background="#aa00ff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_dp"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:background="#ffff00"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

NOTE: This view is being used for ListView row.

[image]

Comment: I just tested your code and it works - The ImageView is indeed vertically centered. Can you post the Activity's code? Perhaps you are doing something there that overrides the Layout params from the XML.

Comment: @Ammar increase the height of relative layout. i got correct view as in image shown

Comment: @nitzanj, @Lollipop! This layout is causing problem when used for list view row. If you try it out of activity, it works perfectly fine. Strange behavior...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a listView you're talking about (next time mention it from the start please...) it changes the problem. Do you use a custom adapter?

If so in your getView when you inflate the xml you should do it like so:

```
view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, viewGroup, false);
```

This makes sure that your layout params are kept - If you give it null as the parent the params are completely ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Remove this

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

and try this

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

to your `ImageView`

Comment: I need to center align just vertically.

Comment: @Ammar give  `android:padding="5dip"` to your `RelativeLayout` and try

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:background="#aa00ff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_dp"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#ffff00"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need to center align just vertically.

Comment: It means a layout obeying android:layout_centerVertical="true".

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#aa00ff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_dp"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#ffff00"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need to center align vertically not horizontally.

Comment: vertically means? not in centre?

Comment: It's not fulfilling my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:background="#aa00ff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_dp"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:background="#ffff00"/>


</LinearLayout>
```